# Sniff which DNS address a program is trying to access?

Tags: proxy, jar, dns

I am running a small registration program (provided by the development tool company) that attempts to access the internet to complete the process.  The corporate firewall is blocking this program and I need to know which DNS address the program is trying to access so that it can be exempted.

Is there a way for me to sniff/detect which DNS address the specific program (JAR) is trying to access?

Update:

The 'network' tool did what I needed.  With the registration program open I ran the portable version and then used the 'NetStat' option.  This gave me the DNS address related to the java program.  Resolving the DNS name confirmed that the address was for the development tool company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tool like this one should do this trick:
http://www.snapfiles.com/get/networxmonitor.html

*(Disclaimer: I've never used this particular one)*